# How to Run Laravel Scheduler Cron Job Continuously

Tags: php, laravel, unix, cron, laravel-5.4

I build online trading application (limit order book) in laravel

In this application user place Buy order or Sell order

and depending on price and quantity of order it get matched.

For order matching i use price/time priority algorithm

i set one cron job that run every minute on server that run order matching script, i use laravel task scheduling for cron job

cron job script is like this

```
fetch 1000 records in database
perform order matching on those records
```

suppose at 12:00:00PM there are 1000 pending orders in database and cron job run at 12:00:00PM and get completed at 12::00::20PM

but order created at 12::01::00PM have to wait for 40 Seconds to execute

so how to setup cron that will run continuously

```
class orderMatch extends Command{
    public function handle(){
        $orders = \App\Order::where(['status' => 0])->limit(1000)->orderBy('id','ASC')->get();
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
             $this->processOrder($order);
        }
    }
}
```

and in kernal.php i have this code

```
$schedule->command('ordermatch:run')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
```

Thanks

Comment: If task ends at 12:00:20 , isn't it normal to wait to 12:01:00 (40 seconds) for the other one to be created?

Comment: yes correct, it have to wait 40 seconds because cron job running every minute, if cron job run at 12.00 next cron run at 12.01,12.02 and so on.

Comment: But you can't handle order that is created at 12:01:00PM at 12:00:20PM since it doesn't exist right?

Comment: yes correct, order created at 12.01.00 handled in next cron

Comment: Really can't understand what you need to do since you say that you already have a cron doing that. provide some code and what you already tried to do, also clarify a little bit what you need.

Comment: Follow what says in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling , if you have an actual problem doing something there post an question. s.o. isn't the place to say "I need you to do this for me"

Comment: i add code in question, so please check it

Comment: And what is the error you're getting/ what do you need to do?

Comment: In application order get created instantly,say at 12:00:00 there are 500 orders and cron run at 12:00 it fetch 1000 records from database (that have created time 12:00) and processOrderMatch on those order and it get completed at 12:00:20

in between 12:00:01 to 12:01:00 there are another 1000 order get generated correct so these order it have to wait for next cron run, so is there way to run cron continuously that run after previous job get finished

Comment: CronJobs and task scheduling is to run something every X time. are you perhaps trying to do something of the likes of queues ? you can queue orders as they are created or every X orders. queues use workers that you can even setup multiple of, multiple stacks etc. check this out https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#introduction

Comment: @Sérgio Reis Thanks, i think it will solve my problem. Once again thanks for your right direction.